# How to apt-get perl module "Template"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, perl, bugzilla

I'm installing Bugzilla and thus I"m working through a list of perl modules to install.  I've managed to get a lot of them up and running except for the below `Template` module.  Is there a apt-get version of this?  I have CPAN installed as well. Since I already have CPAN installed, should I removed it once this is all setup and running?

Is there a site somewhere where I can search for software available via apt-get?

COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

```
         GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD
      Chart: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Chart::Lines
Template-GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template::Plugin::GD::Image
 GDTextUtil: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Text
    GDGraph: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Graph
 Test-Taint: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Test::Taint
```

COMMANDS TO INSTALL REQUIRED MODULES (You *must* run all these commands
and then re-run this script):

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template
```

To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all

*** Installation aborted. Read the messages above. ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you installing Bugzilla manually? ;-)

I don't have an Ubuntu box to check from, but there's a Bugzilla package in Debian (`bugzilla3`), so I'm guessing it's available, even if you need to enable the Universe.  Have you tried using that?  Also, the fact that it exists out there tells me that all required Perl modules are packaged for Ubuntu, although again, you might have to enable the Universe repository.

Trying to mix Distribution provided perl modules with CPAN can get kinda hairy, if you're not careful.  I have a pretty strong preference for keeping them completely separate for all but the most simple cases (by separate, I mean I install a completely new and separate Perl and CPAN installation if I need crazy stuff that's not available via APT repositories, and then use that separate installation just for the application(s) I installed it for).

If I were you, I'd start by getting rid of all the CPAN installed stuff, and try:

```
sudo aptitude install bugzilla3
```

See if that does the trick for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of that... :-\  How do I know if something has a package available for ubuntu?

Comment: How can I access bugzilla now that it's installed?  a locate only turns it being in `/var/lib/mysql/bugzilla`

Comment: You can search for packages using Synaptic (the GUI package manager), or with aptitude, using 'aptitude search FOO'.  As for accessing Bugzilla, I honestly don't know, as I've never install/managed it before.  Keep in mind, however, that the locate DB usually only gets updated from a night cron.  You have to run 'sudo updatedb' to tell it to update right now.  I'd start with looking in /usr/share/doc/bugzilla3/, though, see if there's a README.Debian file that might help you get started.

Comment: This is the first hit on Google. You never answered the question of, how to install Perl's `Text::Template`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

apt-get install libtemplate-perl

**EDIT**

or do you want this one?

apt-get install libtemplate-plugin-gd-perl

Comment: `libtemplate-perl` is already installed and is the latest, the `plugin-gd` didn't resolve it either.  But it did install a few of the optional modules